# Select 'onchange' not working with Jade Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Here I want to call an ajax or an express route  on onchange of dropdown. But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
body
 div(style='display:flex; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto')
    .bs-docs-example.no-code
       select.selectpicker(name='client', id='client',
                    onchange='/route', data-live-search='true')
                    option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Select Client
                        for result in clients
                            option(value='#{result.c_name}') #{result.c_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured out i can't make express route calls from onchange. the only working method is a Javascript call!

ie;

```
            div(style='display:flex; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto')
            .bs-docs-example.no-code
                select.selectpicker(onchange='load();', data-live-search='true')
                    option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Select Client
                        for result in clients
                            option(value='#{result.c_name}') #{result.c_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

onchange is working as expected, it fires on blur. Try using oninput instead.

> oninput="loadFunction()"

or

> HTMLElement.addEventListener('input', ()=> {console.log(HTMLElement.value )})